# Oracle Apex - Interactive Grid rows values are repeating in other rows by clicking

Tags: oracle, grid, rows, apex, interactive

I'm having this issue in Oracle Apex where I want to create a Master/Detail page with interactive grids for each section. The problem is that for some reason, when I click to edit rows in the detail grid, the values seem to "copy" into other fields too.
[This is my grid when the values get copied when clicked in other row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ayXX.png)

For the master grid, this doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: Hi Silvio - Could you please share a test case app?
Take a look at the Sample Interactive Grids app (https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/grand_prix/a12818220220413113554603/master-detail).  The behavior you mentioned is not reproducible here. Thanks.

Comment: I am not quite sure if I would be able to reproduce the behavior in a test case app. I can share you a link with a video of the behavior I mentioned: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DdCglePva6g7JqV_r7kEwRiuSkcW0Xcg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It would be really helpful to have a test case or at least the steps to reproduce this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silvio.
I had the exact same problem. 
I found myself that i defined the wrong column as primary key on the detail IG.
Try it and let me know if helped.
Have a nice day.